# CodingBat Sum67 challenge solution found through Pycharm, but not working on site

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

The Codingbat problem states:
**Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and extending to the next 7 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 7). Return 0 for no numbers.**

I found a solution that works in Pycharm, but not on CodingBat. This code gives me the correct answer when ran through Pycharm, but when I paste it into CodingBat (minus the function call and print statement) I'm receiving an error that states "6 is not in list".  Ive since found a longer solution, but am curious as to why this solution wont work on the site.  Any insight would be appreciated.

```
def sum67(nums):
    if len(nums) == 0:
        return 0

    six = nums.index(6)
    seven = nums.index(7)
    del nums[six:seven+1]
    return sum(nums)


total = sum67([1, 2, 2, 6, 99, 99, 7])
print(total)
```

Comment: task states "...except ignore section**s**..." but your implementation accounts for single section. task mentions **multiple optional** sections. And there could be no such sections at all which is exactly your case - try [1, 2, 2, 5, 99, 99, 7, 2]

Comment: Thank you very much!  Makes complete sense now.